# How to create a protocol buffer for a client server in ballerina?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto3

We  wish  to  build  a  repository  of  functions  that  a  developer  can  assemble  to  build  a  complex  program.

There can  exist  several  versions  of  a  function,  each  with  its  metadata.  This, function  metadata  includes  the  developer's  full  name  and  email address,  the  language  the function  is  implemented  in  and  a  set  of  keywords  related  to  the  functionality  fulfilled  by  the  function.

The versions  of  a  function  can  be  represented  as  a  directed  acyclic  graph.

To  manage  the  repository,  we  use  a  remote  invocation based  gRPC  that  allows  a  client  to  interact  with  a  server  and  execute  the  following  operations:

1. `add_new_fn`:  to  add  either  a  brand  new  function  or  a  new  version  to  an  existing  function;
2. `add_fns`:  to  add  multiple  functions  streamed  by  the  client  (note  that  multiple  versions  of  a  function  are  not  allowed);
3. `delete_fn`:  to  delete  a  function  (this  might  require  reordering  the  versions  of  the  function);
4. `show_fn`:  to  view  a  specific  version  of  a  function;
5. `show_all_fns`:  to  view  all  versions  of  a  function  (the  versions  are  streamed  back  by  the  server)
6. `show_all_with_criteria`:  to  view  all  latest  versions  of  functions  implemented  in  a  given  language  or  related  to  a  set  of keywords  (bi-directional  streaming).

Comment: The API (written as a protobufs) feels straightforward (famous last words!). You'd just need to determine the essential messages that your clients would need to ship to the server that are unique across the methods you summarized above. Is your issue that you want to then call the functions that are defined via gRPC too? I don't understand what you're seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want the API defined:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package foo;

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

// Convention is to name RPC method messages after the method
// Provides flexibility in evolving them distinctly too
service FnRepository {
  rpc AddFn(AddFnPackageRequest) returns (AddFnPackageResponse) {}
  rpc AddFns(stream
 AddFnPackageRequest) returns (stream AddFnPackageResponse) {}
  rpc DeleteFn(DelFnPackageRequest) returns (DelFnPackageResponse) {}
  ...
}

// Requests containing messages provides extensibility
message AddFnPackageRequest {
  FnPackage fn_package = 1;
}
// Unique ID returned here
// Would likely be used to delete
message AddFnPackageResponse {
  string id = 1;
}

message Developer {
  string name = 1;
  string email = 2;
}

// Enum assumes a predefined list of languages
message Fn {
  string name = 1;
  Signature signature = 2;
  enum Language {
    GOLANG = 0;
    RUST = 1;
  }
  Language language = 3;
}

// Conceptually cleaner to define subtypes for e.g. Developer
// This does disconnect e.g. Fn from Developer
message FnPackage {
  Fn fn = 1;
  Developer developer = 2;
  Metadata metadata = 3;
}

message Metadata {
  Developer developer = 1;
  repeated string keywords = 2;
}

// Any is a way to provide polymorphism
// Since Fn signatures are arbitrary types
message Signature {
  google.protobuf.Any params = 1;
  google.protobuf.Any return = 2;
}

...
```

This is written entirely here and so there's no warranty that it will actually compile